# Angular 2 dynamically

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular 2. I was just thrown in the fire to fix an angular 2 app.

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically load a component, here is an example. In this App module, the "AppComponent" is the first to load. I'd like to have an AppComponent for each HTML page, which is the proper way to do this?

1). Create a root app component for each page, ex: HomepageAppComponent, SitesAppComponent (for sites.html), etc?

2). Use one AppComponent and somehow tell it to load the SitesComponent on the sites.html.

Here is the app.module.ts file example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { SitesComponent } from './components/sites/sites.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        SitesComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: You should really follow the tutorial on the angular web site. I highly recommend it, its very well written and covers all these basic concepts like this one you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I am planning on doing that this weekend.

Comment: You can only have one AppComponent. It's the entry point of your application. The other components are here to display ... component. Don't think in term of page but components. You have one page that you can modify using components. And I agree with @Igor, you better follow the tuto :)

Answer (score 0):

If your AppComponent is the same for every page then just put the routeroutlet element in the AppComponent.  then create a route for HomeComponent, SiteComponent...